# Inverting amplifier with and without headphones load

Tags: inverting-amplifier

I made a circuit as the following design:

[image]

R_fb is 2.25k in our case

I am expecting that there wouldn't be negative part of the output waveform.
As expected, without the headphone load the measurement is what we expected.
[image]

But when connected to load, we have an offset:
[image]

The opamp we are using is [LT1366](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1366fb.pdf).
Can someone explain why does not the output waveform hit 0 V?

Comment: What is the headphone inductance?

Answer (score 2):

Even though the LT1366 is listed as rail-to-rail there are limitations. See the datasheet \$V{_O{_L}}\$ parameter. At higher output currents the output can be 200 mV over the negative rail, that is about what you seem to have.

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting a load and seeing the output change significantly the first thing you should look at is the load impedance and the driving capabilities of the amplifier.

You have to look at the datasheet and see what kind of current the opamp can supply, and see if that will be enough for the load and voltage you expect. If it's not enough you need to see if an amp is available that will drive the load, or add some buffering to the existing circuit.